# Can't see database from Azure sql database when trying a migration from Azure data studio

Tags: database, azure, migration, azure-virtual-machine

i try to migrate a database from Azure to a virtual sql machine, but when i try to use the tool from azure data studio, i can't choose any db :

[image]

when i try to import a db from my local server i can see every database :

[image]

Why can't i see the database from azure sql databases when i try to migrate?

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance for your help :)

i try to use my local server and it work, but on sql azure database i can't see the database

Answer (score 0):

As per [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/azure-sql-migration-extension?view=sql-server-ver16) Azure SQL migration extension migrates SQL Server databases to Azure. By using it migrating Azure SQL database is not possible. May be that's the reason for Can't see database from Azure SQL database when trying to migrate it using Azure data studio.
If you want to migrate Azure SQL database, you can use Data-tier application Wizard in Azure data studio.
Right click on server which you want to migrate from then you will get below options

[image]

Select Data-tier application Wizard
Select export the schema and data option and click on next.

[image]

Select export backup settings i.e. server, database and the location where to save the .bacpac file, click on next

[image]

Click on Export

[image]

Export bacpac will be succeeded

[image]

You can import that bacpac file where you want to Migrate the database. In this way you can migrate Azure SQL database.